# How to allow www.example.com and example.com on EC2 Ubuntu Instance on AWS

Tags: redirects, apache2, ubuntu

I have an EC2 Ubuntu Instance that I have Apache2 installed on (along with php, mysql, mycrypt for a Laravel project). I have set up the correct nameservers, and `www.example.com` is coming up online. However, `example.com` (without `www.`) is not working.

I know I have to change something with the vhost, but I am not sure how to do it with the Debian version of Apache2 on the Ubuntu instance.

What file do I edit to do this, and what edit do I have to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how your domain is configured. If it is in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` or (`example.com` in same directory) file, then edit that file. Otherwise it will be in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file.

Find `ServerName domain.com` directive and add this line below that:

```
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

This will make alias also work for same domain. For these settings to make effect you will need to restart apache2 by using this command as `root`:

```
$ service apache2 restart
```

I would also suggest placing `.htaccess` file so it actually redirects `www.example.com` to `example.com` instead of displaying both sites under separate domains. This is also useful for SEO. In your docroot place this in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ok, the only file I'm seeing in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled is 000-default.conf.  And I'm not seeing a conf directory in /etc/apache2/ .  I am only seeing conf-available and conf-enabled.  I found apache2.conf file in the /etc/apache2 directory, but it does not have a line "SeverName domain.com".  Any ideas?

Comment: check `000-default.conf` file. If that one does not have configuration for `domain.com` then it will be `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: There's this commented out in that file: #ServerName www.example.com

Should I uncomment this?  And then add another line ServerName example.com

Comment: I added: ServerName www.domain.com
        ServerAlias domain.com

Comment: And it is still not working for domain.com

Comment: Ok it was a nameserver issue.  I now have domain.com working.  But where is the htaccess file that I change for reroutes?

Comment: It is in root of you public_html directory. If there is no such file just create it (name `.htaccess`)